# What are the best ways for maintaining server time

Tags: datetime, synchronization, client-server

Many applications require server time frequently.

What are the best ways for maintaining server time on client machine with minimized request to server.

Answer (score 4):

The [standard](http://www.ntp.org/) way is to use [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). You can configure it to synchronize as needed, if your machines have decent clocks and unless you want microsecond accuracy or anything like that you should be fine synchronizing once a day or so

Comment: The internal clock is typically a standard quartz oscillator. Provided they're kept at the proper temperature they have a stability of one second per month.